# elasticsearch - Should I organize the data all in one table?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and search in general.

I've a large database that I need to search. 70 tables.

I don't know very well which the best practices for searching a database like this. I've done a large SQL select to 25 database tables to have all the data that I need. I mainly have done this because I will need Facets.

This makes any sense in ElasticSearch? How is the best way to organize the data to be searched in ElasticSearch?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A notable feature of ElasticSearch is the ability to search across multiple Indices/Types or both, this will allow you to structure your data in a similar way as it was structured in the database.

An Indices is essentially ElasticSearch' equivalent to a Database and a Type is that to a table. This allows you to keep the data separated, so for instance having a ElasticSearch definition like so -

```
Index  |  Type

data   -  table1
data   -  table2
data   -  table3
data   -  ....
```

This would allow you to search across all of your types in one query, like so -

```
curl -XPUT <host>:9200/data/table1,table2,table3
```

Or you could have different indexes with the same type, like so -

```
Index  |  Type

data1   -  table
data2   -  table
data3   -  table
data4   -  ....
```

This ability to logically separate your data is a powerful feature of ElasticSearch, dividing the data amongst indices or types also keeps performance in mind.